# Is there a way to make an external table in Snowflake a temporary table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, temp-tables, external-tables

I have an external table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE MY_TABLE
 LOCATION = @MY_STAGE/2022/08/24
 FILE_FORMAT = MY_FILE_FORMAT
 AUTO_REFRESH = TRUE;
```

but is there a way that I can create a "temporary external table" so that the table is not saved? I'm using this to write a file loaded from s3 into a table.

Comment: An external table is not hosted inside of Snowflake, so not clear what you are inferring here ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an external table, you can query the stage files directly:

```sql
select $1, $2, $3
from @my_stage/2022/08/24/file00000000003
limit 10;
```